# Update Activity from service using handler

Tags: android, handler

I want change the state of a `ToggleButton` in my **Activity** when an event occurs in a **service**. Can anybody please help me to implement this using **Handler**?
I mean where should I write the code to create the handler and how to trigger it from a service? I read similar posts but, they were not really helpful in achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public static Runnable runnable;
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

           runnable=new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
            //Change status here

            }

           };
```

From the service

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
handler.post(MyActivity.runnable);
```