# How to Call Method of one activity from another Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have one activity 'A' which extends mapActivity which calls service, and one more Service 'B' which extends service. I'am getting Latitude and Longitude in service 'B'. Now i need call the method in Activity 'A' and  pass the Latitude and Longitude. In that method I have code to display Location. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

- The A activity should start the B activity using `startActivityForResult()` method
- The B activity should set the data to return (latitude and longitude) with `setResult()` before doing `finish()`
- The A activity must override `onActivityResult()` to retrieve data from B

Comment: Activity B extends service he is saying so it is service i think

Answer (score 0):

You are using one Activity and one Service, not two activities, and you want interaction between activity and service. To do so, use BoundService for the same.
See below link for more reference:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Alternatively you can define A messenger in Activity, and can send message from service to activity.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the activity some service. Class that extends the activity is activity.So in your case B is Service

Try to use `runnable` and `handler` to update activity from service

[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771506/update-activity-from-service-using-handler)

Answer (score 0):

Use intent to call one to other

```
   Intent i= new Intent (this,B.class);
   startActivity(i);
```

Its an easyway to call

Answer (score 0):

Intents are used for conveying short message between activities . use Intent and put extras for starting activity from service u need to add extra flags also to start activity from service.

here is reference

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

Create that class object and call the particular method

Answer (score 0):

Using intents is the easiest and the best way. In Activity A have this code to create intent:

```
Intent intent=new intent(this,B.class);
```

/*After the data which needs to be sent to activity B is Processed*/

/*If you want to pass data*/

```
intent.putExtra("Data", data);
  startActivity(i);
```

In Activity B recieve it as:

```
       Intent intent = getIntent();

 String text = intent.getStringExtra("Data");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not create an instance of the activity class. It is wrong. Activity has ui and lifecycle and activity is started by startActivity(intent)

You can use startActivityForResult or you can pass the values from one activity to another using intents and do what is required. But it depends on what you intend to do in the method.

May i know the exact requirement, why you require to call another activity method ??